# "Rewrite to HTTP" rule in web.config broke a Visual Studio local development site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, web-config

When I added the following https redirect rule to my web.config in my local VS test environment, and then built the app for debug, it gave a 403 on the start page.  (The rule itself worked fine in brief standalone test web.config up on Azure.)

After I commented the rule out of the local web.config, I still got the 403.  I restored the previous web.config and still got the 403.  I then changed the start page, and was able to enter the app, and navigate to the original start page.  Then I tried to put the rule back in, and test it all over again, and I started getting config string errors. Finally I restored the entire site from backup, ran it around the whole cycle, and it seems to work.

What might have happened?  Did the rule apply to local IIS, and confuse it?  And so, should I not add the rule until I deploy the site?

```
 <system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
<directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
```

Comment: The local configuration uses a non-standard port when debugging. Your redirect rule does not include the port. Also, the local development web server does not support HTTPS (but IIS express does).

Comment: Thanks, I accept that as the answer (not sure how to indicate it otherwise)